# How to compute sum of combinatorics?

Tags: sum, combinatorics

I am trying to compute

[image]

where C_m^n = m!/n!(m-n)!  As you can see, the sum in the brackets finish either (i) when "n" in the the first C_m^n in the brackets equals zero, or (ii) when "n" in the second C_m^n in the brackets equal "m."  I have tried the following code, which is obviously not correct:

```
clear;clc

L = 10;
l = 8;
q = .99
syms q k i
b = symsum((nchoosek(L-1,L-k)*symsum((nchoosek(l-1,l-1-i)*nchoosek(L-l,L-k - (l-1-i))),i,1,k-1)),k,1,L-1)
```

Comment: What is lowercase l?

Comment: Here, it is equal to 8.  In my problem, it may take any value between 3 and L-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figures it out:

```
L = 10;
l = 8;
q = .99
syms k i
symmax =  @(x,y)feval(symengine,'max',x,y);
b = (2^(L-1)*q/(1-q) + double(symsum(nchoosek(L-1,L-k)*(L-k),k,1,L-1)) + double(symsum(nchoosek(L-1,L-k)*nchoosek(L-l,L-k-(l-1)),k,1,L-1)))...
/(double(symsum(nchoosek(L-1,L-k)*symsum((nchoosek(l-1,l-1-i)*nchoosek(L-l,L-k - (l-1-i))),i,1,symmax(k-1,l-2)),k,2,L-1)));
```